# How do i insert an external html file in a div in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have two divs in my page.the first div contains a navbar having two options.
what i want to do is when i click an option in the navbar, i want the corresponding html file to be loaded in the second div.
How do i do this.please help.

here is my code so far..

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test Document</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
function loadSurveyPage()
{
alert("Survey");
$('#myBody').load('survey.html #myQuestions');
}

function howToSurvey()
{
alert("How to Survey");
$('#myBody').load('howToSurvey.html #myQuestions');
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="myBody">



<div data-role="page" id="indexPage">

<div  data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="navbar" id="navbar">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" rel="external" onclick="howToSurvey()">How To Take The Survey</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="loadSurveyPage()">Take Survey</a></li>    
</ul>
</div>
</div>

<div data-role="content" id="myQuestions"></div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

I get the following error when i click on the option..

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/sp05/Desktop/Self/TMS/testForTab/howToSurvey.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use a local webserver for development (f.ex. IIS for Windows). The problem you have here might be a security issue.
2. You are using the .load() method wrong. The selector argument points to an element on the returning html. Use .get() or .post() instead: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/

Answer (score 0):

I was facing some cross domain issues...I ran the same project on wamp server and it worked perfectly ok..